# How do I use 3DES encryption/decryption in Java?

Tags: java, encryption, 3des

Every method I write to encode a string in Java using 3DES can't be decrypted back to the original string.  Does anyone have a simple code snippet that can just encode and then decode the string back to the original string?

I know I'm making a very silly mistake somewhere in this code. Here's what I've been working with so far:

** note, I am not returning the BASE64 text from the encrypt method, and I am not base64 un-encoding in the decrypt method because I was trying to see if I was making a mistake in the BASE64 part of the puzzle.

```
public class TripleDESTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = "kyle boon";

        byte[] codedtext = new TripleDESTest().encrypt(text);
        String decodedtext  = new TripleDESTest().decrypt(codedtext);

        System.out.println(codedtext);
        System.out.println(decodedtext);
    }

    public byte[] encrypt(String message) {
        try {
            final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
            final byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest("HG58YZ3CR9".getBytes("utf-8"));
            final byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
            for (int j = 0,  k = 16; j < 8;)
            {
                keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
            }

            final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
            final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
            final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

            final byte[] plainTextBytes = message.getBytes("utf-8");
            final byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);
            final String encodedCipherText = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(cipherText);

            return cipherText;    
        }
        catch (java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) { System.out.println("Invalid Algorithm"); }
        catch (javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException e) { System.out.println("No Such Padding"); }
        catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { System.out.println("No Such Algorithm"); }
        catch (java.security.InvalidKeyException e) { System.out.println("Invalid Key"); }
        catch (BadPaddingException e) { System.out.println("Invalid Key");}
        catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) { System.out.println("Invalid Key");}
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { System.out.println("Invalid Key");}

        return null;
    }

    public String decrypt(byte[] message) {
        try
        {
            final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
            final byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest("HG58YZ3CR9".getBytes("utf-8"));
            final byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
            for (int j = 0,  k = 16; j < 8;)
            {
                keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
            }

            final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
            final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
            final Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

            //final byte[] encData = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(message);
            final byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(message);

            return plainText.toString();            
        }
        catch (java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) { System.out.println("Invalid Algorithm"); }
        catch (javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException e) { System.out.println("No Such Padding"); }
        catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { System.out.println("No Such Algorithm"); }
        catch (java.security.InvalidKeyException e) { System.out.println("Invalid Key"); }
        catch (BadPaddingException e) { System.out.println("Invalid Key");}
        catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) { System.out.println("Invalid Key");}
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { System.out.println("Invalid Key");}     
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Your code was fine except for the Base 64 encoding bit (which you mentioned was a test), the reason the output may not have made sense is that you were displaying a raw byte array (doing toString() on a byte array returns its internal Java reference, not the String representation of the **contents**). Here's a version that's just a teeny bit cleaned up and which prints "kyle boon" as the decoded string:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class TripleDESTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String text = "kyle boon";

        byte[] codedtext = new TripleDESTest().encrypt(text);
        String decodedtext = new TripleDESTest().decrypt(codedtext);

        System.out.println(codedtext); // this is a byte array, you'll just see a reference to an array
        System.out.println(decodedtext); // This correctly shows "kyle boon"
    }

    public byte[] encrypt(String message) throws Exception {
        final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
        final byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest("HG58YZ3CR9"
                .getBytes("utf-8"));
        final byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
        for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8;) {
            keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
        }

        final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
        final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

        final byte[] plainTextBytes = message.getBytes("utf-8");
        final byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);
        // final String encodedCipherText = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder()
        // .encode(cipherText);

        return cipherText;
    }

    public String decrypt(byte[] message) throws Exception {
        final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
        final byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest("HG58YZ3CR9"
                .getBytes("utf-8"));
        final byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
        for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8;) {
            keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
        }

        final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
        final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
        final Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

        // final byte[] encData = new
        // sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(message);
        final byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(message);

        return new String(plainText, "UTF-8");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.But in fact,this method uses only two key to encrypt the message:"HG58YZ3CR9" and the "IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);" .  But the most strong option of triple des could use three different key to encrypt the message.So how to do that? I find a mehond in Cipher, which use "SecureRandom" as another parameter.So is this the right way?Thank you very much

Comment: 3DES uses 3, 8-byte keys (stored as 24 bytes in this example). It is common for the 1st and 3rd keys to be the same (i.e. by taking a double length, 16-byte, key you re-use the first component as the 3rd component). To use a triple length key just skip the bit above where the 1st component (bytes 0 - 7) is copied into the space for the 3rd (bytes 16 - 23).

Comment: @AdrianHope-Bailie That advice is wrong as MD5 only outputs 16 bytes, so the rest would be filled with zero's. Just zero's is never going to be a good key.

Comment: This code does do a lot of things correctly, including using a valid padding and mode, character encoding etc.. It however should use PBKDF2 to convert passwords to keys, or use truly random keys. Adding a HMAC calculation over the ciphertext can add significant security as well.

Comment: @owlstead You are correct, I missed the fact that the input data is only 16 bytes. Conveniently disguised by the Array.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24). My point was, in answer to the question specifically, that instead of using the same 8 bytes in the first and last 8 bytes of the 24 byte key (as is common when doing 3DES with 2 * 8 byte key components) one can use 3 unique 8 byte key components.

Comment: The problem with this code is that it uses a static zero bytes IV. It's much better to generate a random IV for each encryption and store it at the front of the ciphertext. It doesn't have to be secret, but it needs to be unpredictable.

Comment: how to conver the cipherText to String?

Answer (score 18):

Here is a solution using the **javax.crypto** library and the apache commons codec library for encoding and decoding in Base64:

```
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class TrippleDes {

    private static final String UNICODE_FORMAT = "UTF8";
    public static final String DESEDE_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME = "DESede";
    private KeySpec ks;
    private SecretKeyFactory skf;
    private Cipher cipher;
    byte[] arrayBytes;
    private String myEncryptionKey;
    private String myEncryptionScheme;
    SecretKey key;

    public TrippleDes() throws Exception {
        myEncryptionKey = "ThisIsSpartaThisIsSparta";
        myEncryptionScheme = DESEDE_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME;
        arrayBytes = myEncryptionKey.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
        ks = new DESedeKeySpec(arrayBytes);
        skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(myEncryptionScheme);
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance(myEncryptionScheme);
        key = skf.generateSecret(ks);
    }


    public String encrypt(String unencryptedString) {
        String encryptedString = null;
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] plainText = unencryptedString.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
            byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
            encryptedString = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encryptedText));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encryptedString;
    }


    public String decrypt(String encryptedString) {
        String decryptedText=null;
        try {
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
            byte[] encryptedText = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedString);
            byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(encryptedText);
            decryptedText= new String(plainText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return decryptedText;
    }


    public static void main(String args []) throws Exception
    {
        TrippleDes td= new TrippleDes();

        String target="imparator";
        String encrypted=td.encrypt(target);
        String decrypted=td.decrypt(encrypted);

        System.out.println("String To Encrypt: "+ target);
        System.out.println("Encrypted String:" + encrypted);
        System.out.println("Decrypted String:" + decrypted);

    }

}
```

Running the above program results with the following output:

```
String To Encrypt: imparator
Encrypted String:FdBNaYWfjpWN9eYghMpbRA==
Decrypted String:imparator
```

Comment: This answer solves the question, but the code introduces all the encoding, mode etc. mistakes to carefully avoided in the code of the question.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. One question, what if the key is shorter than 24 bytes, how can I solve the problem corretcly?

Comment: `key = skf.generateSecret(ks);` here we're generating a key to encrypt, right? so what exactly is `myEncryptionKey`?

Comment: this doesnt seem to work for me when i replace the encryped String above with my string and replace the key with my key. i get the input length is not factor of 8 exception

Answer (score 12):

I had hard times figuring it out myself and this post helped me to find the right answer for my case. When working with financial messaging as ISO-8583 the 3DES requirements are quite specific, so for my especial case the "DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding" combinations wasn't solving the problem. After some comparative testing of my results against some 3DES calculators designed for the financial world I found the the value "DESede/ECB/Nopadding" is more suited for the the specific task.

Here is a demo implementation of my TripleDes class (using the Bouncy Castle provider)

```
    import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
    import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
    import java.security.Security;
    import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
    import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
    import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
    import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
    import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;


    /**
     *
     * @author Jose Luis Montes de Oca
     */
    public class TripleDesCipher {
       private static String TRIPLE_DES_TRANSFORMATION = "DESede/ECB/Nopadding";
       private static String ALGORITHM = "DESede";
       private static String BOUNCY_CASTLE_PROVIDER = "BC";
       private Cipher encrypter;
       private Cipher decrypter;

       public TripleDesCipher(byte[] key) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchPaddingException,
             InvalidKeyException {
          Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
          SecretKey keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, ALGORITHM);
          encrypter = Cipher.getInstance(TRIPLE_DES_TRANSFORMATION, BOUNCY_CASTLE_PROVIDER);
          encrypter.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
          decrypter = Cipher.getInstance(TRIPLE_DES_TRANSFORMATION, BOUNCY_CASTLE_PROVIDER);
          decrypter.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
       }

       public byte[] encode(byte[] input) throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
          return encrypter.doFinal(input);
       }

       public byte[] decode(byte[] input) throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
          return decrypter.doFinal(input);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Just providing any 3DES code does not seem to be an answer to me. Furthermore, the explicit use of ECB and NoPadding, and the use of BC where it is not really needed disqualify this answer in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jlmontesdeoca . Your answer saved my time. I was also stuck with PKCS7Padding.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very simply static encrypt/decrypt class biased on the Bouncy Castle no padding example by Jose Luis Montes de Oca.  This one is using "DESede/ECB/PKCS7Padding" so I don't have to bother manually padding.

```
    package com.zenimax.encryption;

    import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
    import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
    import java.security.Security;
    import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
    import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
    import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
    import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
    import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

    /**
     * 
     * @author Matthew H. Wagner
     */
    public class TripleDesBouncyCastle {
        private static String TRIPLE_DES_TRANSFORMATION = "DESede/ECB/PKCS7Padding";
        private static String ALGORITHM = "DESede";
        private static String BOUNCY_CASTLE_PROVIDER = "BC";

        private static void init()
        {
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        }

        public static byte[] encode(byte[] input, byte[] key)
                throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException,
                NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException,
                NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
            init();
            SecretKey keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, ALGORITHM);
            Cipher encrypter = Cipher.getInstance(TRIPLE_DES_TRANSFORMATION,
                    BOUNCY_CASTLE_PROVIDER);
            encrypter.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
            return encrypter.doFinal(input);
        }

        public static byte[] decode(byte[] input, byte[] key)
                throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException,
                NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException,
                NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
            init();
            SecretKey keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, ALGORITHM);
            Cipher decrypter = Cipher.getInstance(TRIPLE_DES_TRANSFORMATION,
                    BOUNCY_CASTLE_PROVIDER);
            decrypter.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
            return decrypter.doFinal(input);
        }
    }
```

Comment: But it still uses ECB which is a bigger mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static final String UNICODE_FORMAT = "UTF8";
private static final String DESEDE_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME = "DESede";
private KeySpec ks;
private SecretKeyFactory skf;
private Cipher cipher;
byte[] arrayBytes;
private String encryptionSecretKey = "ThisIsSpartaThisIsSparta";
SecretKey key;

public TripleDesEncryptDecrypt() throws Exception {
    convertStringToSecretKey(encryptionSecretKey);
}

public TripleDesEncryptDecrypt(String encryptionSecretKey) throws Exception {
    convertStringToSecretKey(encryptionSecretKey);
}

public SecretKey convertStringToSecretKey (String encryptionSecretKey) throws Exception {
    arrayBytes = encryptionSecretKey.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
    ks = new DESedeKeySpec(arrayBytes);
    skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(DESEDE_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME);
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance(DESEDE_ENCRYPTION_SCHEME);
    key = skf.generateSecret(ks);
    return key;
}

/**
 * Encrypt without specifying secret key
 * 
 * @param unencryptedString
 * @return String
 */
public String encrypt(String unencryptedString) {
    String encryptedString = null;
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] plainText = unencryptedString.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
        byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
        encryptedString = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encryptedText));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return encryptedString;
}

/**
 * Encrypt with specified secret key
 * 
 * @param unencryptedString
 * @return String
 */
public String encrypt(String encryptionSecretKey, String unencryptedString) {
    String encryptedString = null;
    try {
        key = convertStringToSecretKey(encryptionSecretKey);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] plainText = unencryptedString.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
        byte[] encryptedText = cipher.doFinal(plainText);
        encryptedString = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(encryptedText));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return encryptedString;
}


/**
 * Decrypt without specifying secret key
 * @param encryptedString
 * @return
 */
public String decrypt(String encryptedString) {
    String decryptedText=null;
    try {
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encryptedText = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedString);
        byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(encryptedText);
        decryptedText= new String(plainText);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return decryptedText;
}

/**
 * Decrypt with specified secret key
 * @param encryptedString
 * @return
 */
public String decrypt(String encryptionSecretKey, String encryptedString) {
    String decryptedText=null;
    try {
        key = convertStringToSecretKey(encryptionSecretKey);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encryptedText = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedString);
        byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(encryptedText);
        decryptedText= new String(plainText);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return decryptedText;
}
```

Comment: Enhancing @oniero's codes, this helps you to use preferable secret key and you initiate the class once and be able to decrypt and encrypt.

Main method wasn't added, so you can add main method or copy oniero's main method

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.Key;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.Base64.Encoder;


/**
 * 
 * @author shivshankar pal
 * 
 *         this code is working properly. doing proper encription and decription
           note:- it will work only with jdk8

 * 

 * 
 */

public class TDes {
    private static byte[] key = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
            0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0x02, 0x02,
            0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02, 0x02 };

    private static byte[] keyiv = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
            0x00 };



     public static String encode(String args) {


        System.out.println("plain data==>  " + args);

        byte[] encoding;
        try {
            encoding = Base64.getEncoder().encode(args.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        System.out.println("Base64.encodeBase64==>" + new String(encoding));
        byte[] str5 = des3EncodeCBC(key, keyiv, encoding);

        System.out.println("des3EncodeCBC==>  " + new String(str5));

        byte[] encoding1 = Base64.getEncoder().encode(str5);
        System.out.println("Base64.encodeBase64==> " + new String(encoding1));
        return new String(encoding1);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    public static String decode(String args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("encrypted data==>" + new String(args.getBytes("UTF-8")));


        byte[] decode = Base64.getDecoder().decode(args.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println("Base64.decodeBase64(main encription)==>" + new String(decode));

        byte[] str6 = des3DecodeCBC(key, keyiv, decode);
        System.out.println("des3DecodeCBC==>" + new String(str6));
        String data=new String(str6);
        byte[] decode1 = Base64.getDecoder().decode(data.trim().getBytes("UTF-8"));
        System.out.println("plaintext==>  " + new String(decode1));
        return new String(decode1);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "u mistaken in try block";

        }



    private static byte[] des3EncodeCBC(byte[] key, byte[] keyiv, byte[] data) {
        try {
            Key deskey = null;
            DESedeKeySpec spec = new DESedeKeySpec(key);
            SecretKeyFactory keyfactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("desede");
            deskey = keyfactory.generateSecret(spec);

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("desede/ CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            IvParameterSpec ips = new IvParameterSpec(keyiv);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, deskey, ips);
            byte[] bout = cipher.doFinal(data);
            return bout;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("methods qualified name" + e);
        }
        return null;

    }

    private static byte[] des3DecodeCBC(byte[] key, byte[] keyiv, byte[] data) {
        try {
            Key deskey = null;
            DESedeKeySpec spec = new DESedeKeySpec(key);
            SecretKeyFactory keyfactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("desede");
            deskey = keyfactory.generateSecret(spec);

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("desede/ CBC/NoPadding");//PKCS5Padding NoPadding
            IvParameterSpec ips = new IvParameterSpec(keyiv);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, deskey, ips);

            byte[] bout = cipher.doFinal(data);


            return bout;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("methods qualified name" + e);
        }

        return null;

    }

}
```