# Simple Java encryption w/ JSON-friendly encoding?

Tags: java, json, web-services, encryption

I'm looking for a simple Java encryption solution that will allow me to specify the encoding such that the encrypted data can be embedded in a JSON document.

**Why?** My web service returns a descriptive JSON message when errors occur.  In the event of an internal server error, I'd like to include a field that contains diagnostic information, however I want to encrypt this data to avoid potential security issues.

I'm going for something similar to YouTube's Internal Server Error, plus JSON and minus monkeys.:

[image: YouTube 500 error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Hot Licks said, encrypt using your choice method to achieve the level of SECURITY you want vs performance/simplicity.  Then use Base64 encoding on that data to make it easy to transport in your JSON.  There are several Base64 libraries around.  Have a look at these stack overflow answers for good Java encryption options:

[Java simple encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354803/java-simple-encryption)

[How to encrypt String in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205135/how-to-encrypt-string-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

Encrypt the data and return it as a [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) character string.