# To implement Encryption using 3DES in java

Tags: java, security

I have to implement 3DES encryption using 3DES in java.

Could you please suggest and provide good samples to proceed.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227/how-do-i-use-3des-encryption-decryption-in-java

Comment: do you need to really implement it or just to use the algorithm? (also if from a library)

Comment: I have to use TripleDES for encryption and decryption.

Comment: You'd be a lot better off using an existing library than trying to implement it yourself unless you're very familiar with implementing encryption algorithms.

Comment: I did not quite understand what did u mean by saying use an existing library.

So I have implement ssl communication using SSLV3 protocols before.
Now I need to use TripleDES . Hence, I needed help.

Comment: TripleDES is extremely old and no one uses it anymore.  SSLV3 doesn't like using TrippleDES, although it is on the list of supported ciphers.   I suspect you are making a serious mistake and Rewriting ssl is a serious mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) library. Look at: [DESedeEngine](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.6/org/bouncycastle/crypto/engines/DESedeEngine.html)