# Triple DES encryption and decryption in Java

Tags: java, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use 3des encryption/decryption in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227/how-do-i-use-3des-encryption-decryption-in-java)

I am looking for a solution for the Triple DES encryption and decryption in Java. 
I want to store a password encrypted in Triple DES in a file - and I want the program to decrypt this password and use it on runtime.

Can anyone point me to resources/tutorials or even full solutions on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [bounce castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html) lib?

There are a lot of examples and encrytion options.