# How to use 3DES algorithm on Android?

Tags: java, android, 3des

On the server side, the encyption/decryption of the password field is done in C#.

Now, i need to implement same functionality in my android application. So, i followed this tutorial: http://ttux.net/post/3des-java-encrypter-des-java-encryption/ as below:

```
    import java.security.MessageDigest; 
import java.security.spec.KeySpec; 
import java.util.Arrays; 

import javax.crypto.Cipher; 
import javax.crypto.SecretKey; 
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory; 
import javax.crypto.spec.DESedeKeySpec; 
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec; 

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64; 

public class Encrypter { 
  private KeySpec keySpec; 
  private SecretKey key; 
  private IvParameterSpec iv; 

  public Encrypter(String keyString, String ivString) { 
    try { 
      final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5"); 
      final byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest(Base64.decodeBase64(keyString.getBytes("utf-8"))); 
      final byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24); 
      for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8;) { 
    keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++]; 
      } 

      keySpec = new DESedeKeySpec(keyBytes); 

      key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DESede").generateSecret(keySpec); 

      iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivString.getBytes()); 
    } catch(Exception e) { 
      e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
  } 

  public String encrypt(String value) { 
    try { 
      Cipher ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding","SunJCE"); 
      ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv); 

      if(value==null) 
    return null; 

      // Encode the string into bytes using utf-8 
      byte[] utf8 = value.getBytes("UTF8"); 

      // Encrypt 
      byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8); 

      // Encode bytes to base64 to get a string 
      return new String(Base64.encodeBase64(enc),"UTF-8"); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
      e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
    return null; 
  } 

  public String decrypt(String value) { 
    try { 
      Cipher dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding","SunJCE"); 
      dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv); 

      if(value==null) 
    return null; 

      // Decode base64 to get bytes 
      byte[] dec = Base64.decodeBase64(value.getBytes()); 

      // Decrypt 
      byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec); 

      // Decode using utf-8 
      return new String(utf8, "UTF8"); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
      e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
    return null; 
  } 
}
```

but i dont know what values i need to provide for KeyValue and ivValue for the above code. Please help me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use 3des encryption/decryption in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227/how-do-i-use-3des-encryption-decryption-in-java)

Comment: 3DES is not recommended now. Use AES256. [This](https://github.com/ryan652/EasyCrypt/) is a great library for secure AES encryption on Android which support multiple datatypes.

Answer (score 6):

Use this code to encrypt your string

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import android.util.Base64;
//string encryption
public class EncryptionHelper {



    // Encrypts string and encode in Base64
    public static String encryptText(String plainText) throws Exception {
        // ---- Use specified 3DES key and IV from other source --------------
        byte[] plaintext = plainText.getBytes();//input
        byte[] tdesKeyData = Constants.getKey().getBytes();// your encryption key

        byte[] myIV = Constants.getInitializationVector().getBytes();// initialization vector

        Cipher c3des = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        SecretKeySpec myKey = new SecretKeySpec(tdesKeyData, "DESede");
        IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(myIV);

        c3des.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myKey, ivspec);
        byte[] cipherText = c3des.doFinal(plaintext);
        String encryptedString = Base64.encodeToString(cipherText,
                Base64.DEFAULT);
        // return Base64Coder.encodeString(new String(cipherText));
        return encryptedString;
    }

}
```

This is how you can encrypt the string

```
String encryptedPassword = EncryptionHelper.encryptText(edtText.getText().toString());
```

**EDIT**
Code for `Constants.java`

```
     Class Constants {
         private final String initializationVector = "INITALIZATION_VECTOR";
         private final String ecnryptionKey = "ENCRYPTION_KEY";
         public static String getInitializationVector() {
             return initializationVector;
         }
         public static String getKey() {
             return ecnryptionKey;
         }
     }
```

Comment: Encryption is good what about the decrytText function? do you have source for that?

Comment: Hei @onkar . Can you post a decrypt version?

Comment: byte[] tdesKeyData = Constants.getKey().getBytes();// your encryption key

        byte[] myIV = Constants.getInitializationVector().getBytes();// initialization vector

Comment: what is Constants.getKey().getBytes();

Comment: @onkar what is the programming of getInitializationVector() method ??? can u help me to get the code of this ...

Answer (score 1):

Triple DES is called `"DESede"` (DES using single DES Encrypt, Decrypt, Encrypt for encryption) in both Java and Android runtimes. So it is build in functionality which can be access through the [`Cipher`](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher.html) class. It also lists the available algorithms. For triple DES you could use "DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding"`. Don't forget to supply it a random IV of 8 bytes.

Triple DES should only be used for backwards compatibility. If you decide to use it at least supply it 24 bytes of key material, otherwise there is a chance that your ciphertext can be cracked. For a more modern approach use AES, preferably in an authenticated mode such as GCM (`"AES/GCM/NoPadding"`). Note that GCM requires a unique nonce of 12 bytes.