# triple des encryption and decryption in Android

Tags: android, encryption, cryptography, tripledes

I have a key and data in string format from json. I want to encrypt and decrypt the data using triple des method using the key. Is there any libraries are available for triple des in android? If not available please give me a solution for my question.

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: Also see [How to use 3DES algorithm on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16336017/608639), [How do I use 3DES encryption/decryption in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20227/608639), [Difference between DESede and TripleDES for cipher.getInstance()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17280104/608639), etc.

Comment: If somebody could close this as a dupe of the first link given by jww then I'd be happy. I already copied my answer over there (as the current answer is code only).