# How to use three keys with triple des(3des) in Java

Tags: java, encryption, des, 3des

I found a link in stackoverflow here [use-3des-encryption-decryption-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227/how-do-i-use-3des-encryption-decryption-in-java),but in fact the method uses only two parameter:HG58YZ3CR9" and the "`IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);`" 

But the most strong option of triple des could use three different key to encrypt the message.So how to do that? I find a mehond in Cipher, which use "SecureRandom" as another parameter.So is this the right way?

The first method code is below:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class TripleDESTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String text = "kyle boon";

        byte[] codedtext = new TripleDESTest().encrypt(text);
        String decodedtext = new TripleDESTest().decrypt(codedtext);

        System.out.println(codedtext); // this is a byte array, you'll just see a reference to an array
        System.out.println(decodedtext); // This correctly shows "kyle boon"
    }

    public byte[] encrypt(String message) throws Exception {
        final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        final byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest("HG58YZ3CR9"
                .getBytes("utf-8"));
        final byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
        for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8;) {
            keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
        }

        final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
        final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

        final byte[] plainTextBytes = message.getBytes("utf-8");
        final byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);
        // final String encodedCipherText = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder()
        // .encode(cipherText);

        return cipherText;
    }

    public String decrypt(byte[] message) throws Exception {
        final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        final byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest("HG58YZ3CR9"
                .getBytes("utf-8"));
        final byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
        for (int j = 0, k = 16; j < 8;) {
            keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
        }

        final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
        final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(new byte[8]);
        final Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

        // final byte[] encData = new
        // sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(message);
        final byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(message);

        return new String(plainText, "UTF-8");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to inter-operate with some existing code? If not why are you using 3DES instead of AES?

Comment: @CodesInChaos The server uses 3des for many years and our manager doesn't want to change the algorithm of the server

Answer (score 2):

As per [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html), simply pass the cipher a key that is 168 bits long.

> Keysize must be equal to 112 or 168.
>
> A keysize of 112 will generate a Triple DES key with 2 intermediate keys, and a keysize of 168 will generate a Triple DES key with 3 intermediate keys.

Your code seems to do something questionable to make up for the fact that the output of MD5 is only 128 bits long.

Copy-pasting cryptographic code off the internet will not produce secure applications. Using a static IV compromises several reasons why CBC mode is better than ECB. If you are using a static key, you should probably consider generating random bytes using a secure random number generator instead of deriving the key from a short ASCII string. Also, there is absolutely no reason to use Triple DES instead of AES in new applications.

Comment: Thank you very much.And will it be better if I use "SHA-1" instead of MD5 ? In fact, I don't think I have used the code which encrypt by MD5 directly .And I also confuse that what can I do for   3 intermediate keys.Must I use  a secure random number generator? And if I do so,how can I decrypt the code?Thank you very much!

Comment: Instead of storing an ASCII string and then hashing that every time, you should generate the key bytes once and then store those bytes.

Comment: Cool!But  I had  to let the server decrypt the code too,so I think it is hard to synchronise the random number

Comment: I can't see how storing bytes and storing a string are different in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, the for-next loop to generate the DES ABA key does seem correct. *Note that you can provide DESede with a 16 byte key from Java 7 onwards, which amounts to the same thing*.

That said, the code you've shown leaves a lot to be desired:

I is not secure:

- the key is not generated by a Password Based Key Derivation Function (PBKDF) using the (password?) string
- the key is composed of two keys instead of three (using a triple DES or TDEA with an ABA key)
- the IV is set to all zero's instead of being randomized
- the "password" string is too short

Furthermore the following code mistakes can be seen:

- using `new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder()` which is in the Sun proprietary packages (which can be removed or changed during any upgrade of the runtime)
- throwing `Exception` for platform exceptions and runtime exceptions (not being able to decrypt is handled the same way as not being able to instantiate the `Cipher`)
- requesting 24 bytes instead of 16 within the `Arrays.copyOf()` call (which seems to return 24 SHA-1 output while there are only 20 bytes)

To generate a 3DES 24 byte (168 bits used) DES ABC key from a password (like) String you should use PBKDF-2. Adding an authentication tag is also very important if man-in-the-middle attacks or padding oracle  apply. It would be much secure and much more practical to upgrade to AES if you can control the algorithms being used as well.