# RSA authentication Android java client, app engine pycrypto server, encoded private key

Tags: android, rsa, signature, pycrypto

I have an Android client sending RSA-signed messages to an App Engine server using Python and the pycrypto library. The server creates the key pair and sends the private key, encrypted, to the client. I am having trouble unpacking the received key on the Android/Java/client side for use with the signature library. The key, as it is stored looks like this:
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
    Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
    DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,9C527448BB17EA68
    jodXz.....
    .....+FxMnI
    -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
This is the sort of thing that hundreds of people must have done already, but the examples I have found fail almost immediately.
Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,9C527448BB17EA68

jodXz..... .....+FxMnI
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

"DEK-Info" contains information on how the following key data was encrypted: with Triple DES and CBC chaining mode. 9C527448BB17EA68 is input vector. Along with passphrase it allows to decrypt private key data.

[Example of Triple DES in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227/how-do-i-use-3des-encryption-decryption-in-java)