# DES-Encrypt a byte array, java

Tags: java, encryption, encoding, des

I'm using this code for DES-encryption: [How do I use 3des encryption/decryption in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227/how-do-i-use-3des-encryption-decryption-in-java)

Now, I want to encrypt a byte array with this. How can I do that?

I have changed the name of algo from `DESede` to `DES` and am obviously using an 8-byte key (not 24).

Comment: Why do you want to use DES? It's not secure anymore nowadays.

Comment: Its implementation based. I'm implementing something that uses DES number of times to encrypt data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cipher#doFinal` takes and returns `byte[]`. The only thing that you need to do is removing the additional encoding steps like

```
message.getBytes("utf-8") // before encryption
```

and

```
new String(plainText, "UTF-8") // after decryption
```

Obviously, you need to change the method signature from `String` to `byte[]` for both encryption and decryption.