# How can we do Triple Decryption in java?

Tags: java

I am using a MOL API for VOUCHER recharges. Which returns a PIN number in response is successful. That PIN number will be an encrypted text and I need to triple decrypt it!

I contacted the API support, They provided with the code below:

```
byte[] PinBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedText.getBytes("utf-8"));
byte[] VectorBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(vectorKey.getBytes("utf-8"));
byte[] SecretKeyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(secretKey.getBytes("utf-8")); 
TripleDESProvider = CreateTripleDESCryptographicProvider(VectorBytes, SecretKeyBytes)
    DecryptedBytes = TripleDESProvider.Decrypt(PinBytes)
```

Here VectorBytes and SecretKeyBytes are security keys provided by them and PinBytes are the response PIN number which is encrypted.

I googled while I was not able to get a correct solution with these three parameters. Any help, please?

I tried this:

```
try
        {
            String encryptedText = "FN0hbSrVzkqhe+w2rQefAQ==";
            String vectorKey = "7EsBtzAJjMg=";
            //32 bit key
            String secretKey = "08061052989102040806105298910204";
            byte[] PinBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedText.getBytes("utf-8"));
            byte[] VectorBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(vectorKey.getBytes("utf-8"));
            byte[] SecretKeyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(secretKey.getBytes("utf-8"));
            final MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
            final byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest(SecretKeyBytes);
            final byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
            for (int j = 0,  k = 16; j < 8;)
            {
                keyBytes[k++] = keyBytes[j++];
            }

            final SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
            final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(VectorBytes);
            final Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);

            //final byte[] encData = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(message);
            final byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(PinBytes);

            System.out.println(plainText.toString());           
        }
        catch (java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) { System.out.println("Invalid Algorithm"); }
        catch (javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException e) { System.out.println("No Such Padding"); }
        catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { System.out.println("No Such Algorithm"); }
        catch (java.security.InvalidKeyException e) { System.out.println("Invalid Key"); }
        catch (BadPaddingException e) { System.out.println("Invalid Key");}
        catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) { System.out.println("Invalid Key");}
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { System.out.println("Invalid Key");}     
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Error is Invalid KEY

**The document they provide is;**

Convert Encrypted Pin into Byte Array from Base64 format

```
PinBytes = ConvertFromBase64String ("FN0hbSrVzkqhe+w2rQefAQ==")
```

As Vector Key and Secret Key are provided in Base64 format, thus we need to convert both data into Byte Array as well

```
VectorBytes = ConvertFromBase64String ("xxxxxxxxx") 
SecretKeyBytes = ConvertFromBase64String ("xxxxxxxxxxxx")
```

Please create your Triple DES Cryptographic Provider and set your IV byte array and Secret Key byte array into your Provider.

```
TripleDESProvider = CreateTripleDESCryptographicProvider(VectorBytes, SecretKeyBytes)
```

Please invokes Triple DES Provider decrypt method.

```
DecryptedBytes = TripleDESProvider.Decrypt(PinBytes)
```

Finally convert back decrypted bytes back to string.

ConvertToString(DecryptedBytes)

The result should be 8157151550.

Comment: by the way this is java code

Comment: @amicoderozer But they told they don't have the java code!! CreateTripleDESCryptographicProvider is this a built in function?

Comment: no this is not, i think you have to write your own method to decrypt. Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227/how-do-i-use-3des-encryption-decryption-in-java

Comment: @amicoderozer Yes i found that but there maybe i have an confusion here they are providing VectorBytes and SecretKeyBytes.So i am confused !

Comment: Could you give us example data?

Comment: Are you talking about triple-DES?

Comment: @EJP Yes TripleDES decryption

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the right approach but with `AES` encryption it works.  They provided you the vector, use it to initialize the `IVParameterSpec`, then create `Key` object and `Cipher` instance:

```
// this is the encripted text
byte[] PinBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedText.getBytes("utf-8"));

byte[] VectorBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(vectorKey.getBytes("utf-8"));

byte[] SecretKeyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(secretKey.getBytes("utf-8")); 

// initialize the vector with the one you receive               
IvParameterSpec spec = new IvParameterSpec(VectorBytes);

// create the key. DESede should be correct, but if it doesn't work try also with DES
Key key = new SecretKeySpec(SecretKeyBytes, "DESede");

// Initialize the cipher
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

// decrypt the string
c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, spec);
byte[] decodedDecryptedBytes = c.doFinal(PinBytes);
```

`Base64` object i use is from [apache common codec library](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec), but you can use the library you want.

Comment: are you sure the key you provide in your example is correct? As far as I know it should be 24 bytes long. Yours is 32

Comment: Yes this is the key provided!!

Comment: @KarthikCP The (secret) key used doesn't seem to be base64 encoded. As stated in the previous comment, the key size should be different (168 or 112 bit according to a 3des spec). If you treat is as decimal, converting you will get 14 bytes (112 bit)

Comment: @gusto2 Okk.. So how could i convert it to 112bit

Comment: @gusto2 But in their documentation they are saying the secret key is base64

Comment: @KarthikCP but the one you use in your example is not. And it's not 24 bytes long, they should have give you a base64 string (example: `FN0hbSrVzkqhe+w2rQefAQ==`)

Comment: @gusto2. ALright! Then let me check with them again!!

Comment: @KarthikCP the key treated as base64 encoded, it simply doesn't comply with the 3des standard.. So the simplest option for you is asking for a properly (base64) encoded  key. To convert yourself maybe you could use BigInt or BaseNCodec (from apache commons-codec)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I Got this answer with same provided secretKey!!

```
try
        {
            byte[] PinBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedText);
            byte[] VectorBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(vectorKey);
            byte[] SecretKeyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(secretKey);
         // initialize the vector with the one you receive               
            IvParameterSpec spec = new IvParameterSpec(VectorBytes);

            // create the key. DESede should be correct, but if it doesn't work try also with DES
            Key key = new SecretKeySpec(SecretKeyBytes, "DESede");

            // Initialize the cipher
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

            // decrypt the string
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, spec);
            byte[] decodedDecryptedBytes = c.doFinal(PinBytes);
            return new String(decodedDecryptedBytes, "UTF-8");      
        }
        catch (java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) { System.out.println("Invalid Algorithm"); }
        catch (javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException e) { System.out.println("No Such Padding"); }
        catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { System.out.println("No Such Algorithm"); }
        catch (java.security.InvalidKeyException e) { System.out.println("InvalidKeyException : Invalid Key"); }
        catch (BadPaddingException e) { System.out.println("BadPaddingException : Invalid Key");}
        catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) { System.out.println("IllegalBlockSizeException : Invalid Key");}
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) { System.out.println("UnsupportedEncodingException : Invalid Key");}     
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
```

The Mistake was doing this:

```
 byte[] SecretKeyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(secretKey.getBytes("utf-8"));
```

I don't know why this happens! But by removing that I got the answer!!