# how to encrypt passwords for password manager in java

Tags: java, database, encryption, passwords, project

I want to make a java password manager so I want to encrypt the passwords and insert it into the database then retrieve it decrypted
can you please explain to me how to do it?
And what type of encryption algorithms should I use?

Comment: can you explain what is the difference please

Comment: thank you for the answer but if i use hashing how to retrieve it as readable text in my application

Comment: yes but the problem is the user is not going write down the password because it's a password manager where he use the application to see his accounts passwords

Comment: why did u delete it

Comment: can you please give me the way of doing aes for java

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. "can you please give me the way of doing aes for java" - SO is not a code writing service. Start your research for code with "AES string encryption"

Comment: @Yahya I've added the AES example for you, although Micheal Fehr does have a point.

Comment: wdym it's not a writing service
in the about page they said "Helping developers and technologists write the script of the future"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the most popular encryption methods include:

- Data Encryption Standard (DES) Encryption (WARNING: Unsecure)
- TripleDES Encryption
- RSA Encryption
- Advanced Encryption Standard (AES) Encryption

It's not generally recommended to make your own encryption method, because there is a high possibility it is not as secure as ones that have been rigorously tested for integrity. (Like the ones as mentioned)

You can find some examples below on how to use them:

- [Use DES for Java](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard#Java)
- [Use TripleDES for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227/how-do-i-use-3des-encryption-decryption-in-java)
- [Use AES for Java](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/java-security/java-aes-encryption-example/)

Comment: Thats right! I would combine a standard-encryption method with a seed (manual password to enter). Without the seed, It't impossible to recover the stored passwords.

Comment: Why do you recommend "DES" as your first choice as it is named as "**UNSECURE**" and should not any longer used, especially for a password manager?

Comment: I think the modern encryption type things use RSA encryption on the key for AES, so it would probably be useful to include a resource for RSA as well